# How to create multiple buttons with recycleview

Tags: android, android-studio

My app shows multiple ImageButton with recycleview, everything works fine, what i want is when a person clicks a Imagebutton, they will be directed to the activity "monactivitefinal" and keep the content of "article.ifram" so that I use it on this new activity.
all the Imagebutton redirect to the same activity "monactivitefinal" only the variable "article.ifram" that changes

This is my code :

```
class Article(var id: Int, var nom: String, var lienimg: String, var ifram: String){
}

class ArticleAdapter(var articles: ArrayList<Article>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        var vue=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.listevisitess,
            parent,
            false
        )
        return MyViewHolder(vue)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return articles.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var article = articles.get(position)
        holder.nomvisite.setText(article.nom)
        holder.lieimgvisite.setText(article.lienimg)
        holder.ifram.setText(article.ifram)

        var urldelimg:String = article.lienimg 
        Glide.with(holder.imagedubloc.context).load(urldelimg).into(holder.imagedubloc) 


    }

    class MyViewHolder(var vue: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(vue){
        var nomvisite=vue.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nom_visite)
        var lieimgvisite=vue.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lienimg)
        var ifram=vue.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ifram)
        var imagedubloc=vue.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagedubloc) 
    }


}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nom_visite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lienimg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    />


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imagedubloc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ifram"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="25dp"
                    />

</LinearLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclevirtuel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an extra field within your `Intent` that you are using to navigate to the new activity, you code would be like this:

```
class ArticleAdapter(var articles: ArrayList<Article>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        var vue=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.listevisitess,
            parent,
            false
        )
        return MyViewHolder(vue)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return articles.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var article = articles.get(position)
        holder.nomvisite.setText(article.nom)
        holder.lieimgvisite.setText(article.lienimg)
        holder.ifram.setText(article.ifram)

        var urldelimg:String = article.lienimg 
        Glide.with(holder.imagedubloc.context).load(urldelimg).into(holder.imagedubloc) 

        // here you pass your "ifram" value to the activity you're navigating to
        holder.imagedubloc.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(holder.vue.context,monactivitefinal::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("ifram", article.ifram)
            })
        }

    }

    class MyViewHolder(var vue: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(vue){
        var nomvisite=vue.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nom_visite)
        var lieimgvisite=vue.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lienimg)
        var ifram=vue.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ifram)
        var imagedubloc=vue.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagedubloc) 
    }


}
```

in your activity you can get "ifram" value as follows:

```
val ifram = getIntent().getStringExtra("ifram")
```

Comment: thankyou, but i have this error : Classifier 'Context' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here

Comment: and if i use : startActivity(holder.vue.context, Intent(holder.imagedubloc.context,monactivitefinal::class.java).apply 
i have this errorr (in the same line) : No value passed for parameter 'p2'

Comment: I'm very sorry, I had a 'typo' in my code, I edited it as follows: `startActivity(Intent(holder.vue.context,monactivitefinal::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("ifram", article.ifram) })`
@admindunet

Answer (score 1):

You need add listener to handle onClick Event, then the ButtonListActivity needs to implement this interface and init your adapter with it like this.

Listener

```
interface ImageButtonClickListener {

    fun onImageButtonClick(articleIfram: String)
}
```

Activity with list of buttons

```
class ButtonListActivity : AppCompactActivity(), ImageButtonClickListener {

    private val adapter: ArticleAdapter = ArticleAdapter(ArrayList(), this)

    override fun onImageButtonClick(articleIfram: String) {
        val intent = Intent(context, Monactivitefinal::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("articleIfram", articleIfram)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Your adapter

```
class ArticleAdapter(
    val onImageButtonClickListener: ImageButtonClickListener, 
    var articles: ArrayList<Article>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var article = articles.get(position)
        imagedubloc.setOnClickListener {
            onImageButtonClickListener.onImageButtonClick(article. ifram)
        }
    }
}
```

You could use lambda if you don't want to add listener

Activity with list of buttons

```
class ButtonListActivity : AppCompactActivity(), ImageButtonClickListener {

    private val onImageButtonClick: (String) -> Unit = {
        val intent = Intent(context, Monactivitefinal::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("articleIfram", articleIfram)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private val adapter: ArticleAdapter = ArticleAdapter(ArrayList(), onImageButtonClick)
}
```

Your adapter

```
class ArticleAdapter(
    val onImageButtonClickListener: (String) -> Unit, 
    var articles: ArrayList<Article>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var article = articles.get(position)
        imagedubloc.setOnClickListener {
            onImageButtonClickListener(article. ifram)
        }
    }
}
```